# React-Routes not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

here is my app.js

```
<Router>
        <Header title="My Todos List" />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/" render={() => {
            return (
              <>
                <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
                <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
              </>)
          }} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
```

the render function is not rendering anything in my home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use element like this

```
          <Route path="/" elemen={      
              <>
                <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
                <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
              </>
             }
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `children` prop for `render` prop from RR V5+ - [see the migration docs for ref](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.3/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v51)

so change the `Route` as

```
<Route
  path="/"
  children={
    <>
      <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
      <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete} />
    </>
  }
/>;
```